# script zenity + inotify

Tags: scripts

I would like to have a simple script to notify the user in the screen, each time a new folder or file is created in a shared folder. The output should be like "You have a new file/folder named newfile/newfolder". I'm using this script, but I'm not able to put the newfile/newfolder name in zenity output.

```
while inotifywait -r -e create ~/Documents/Process
do
    zenity --warning -- ????
done
```

thks
Djames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a similar script:

```
while true
do
    fileName=$(inotifywait -r -e create ~/Documents/Process | sed -r 's/^.*CREATE(,ISDIR)*\s+(.*)$/\2/g')
    zenity --warning --text="You have a new file/folder named $fileName"
done
```

The `fileName` variable holds the extracted file name that `inotifywait` detects and outputs. (It is filtered from the output by using a `sed` command.)

Then the `$fileName` is displayed by `zenity` using the `--text=` switch.

These two lines run in an endless loop to enable detection of other creation events. Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to abort the watch.

Comment: thks! It works!, but I'll make some more tests to check if everything is ok!

Comment: I'm glad you've found it useful! I've tested it with some weird filenames, but make sure to comment on any problems.

Comment: Ok, a little more complicated. I've looking in sed manual, what you have donne, but I'could understand quite well...the inotify can have 3 outputs: "CREATE" (file), "CREATE,ISDIR" (directory), or empty when deleting file ou folder. The important output is the text right next to "CREATE" or "CREATE,ISDIR". Can you help? thks!

Comment: @Djames Updated for directory detection, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: thks very much, it's working! ;)